# Load Silverlight Canvas as a seperate XAML File?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0

I want to be able to store various Canvas items in seperate XAML files so for example they are declared as:

```
<canvas x:Class="Item.One" Height="300" Width="400">
...
</canvas>
```

and another like this

```
<canvas x:Class="Item.Two" Height="300" Width="400">
...
</canvas>
```

I am wondering why I cannot get this to work when I try and load them in as classes I get a parser error, I can do this fine in WPF but not in Silverlight 3.0, what can you do to have to have XAML work as objects rather than resources?

---

Just to help the Parser error is

```
AG_E_PARSER_BAD_TYPE
```

And a real example that does not work:

```
<Canvas x:Class="Cards.Appointment.ZuneVertical" x:Name="ZuneVertical"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="240" Height="320" Background="White">
</Canvas>
```

---

In my code I want to do this:

```
Preview.Children.Add(Item.One)
```

Where Preview is a Grid within a ScrollView which is where I want the XAML to be loaded into, ie the Canvas, there a various versions of Canvas I want to load into this Preview Pane, each one is a Class as XAML in WPF, but cannot seem to get this to work in Silverlight 3.0 without the parsing error, tried UserControls but this has the same problem!

Comment: "when I try and load them in as classes"?  Could you expand on what you consider Loading something as class involves?

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear there, will amend my question to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it was a problem with the Namespace of my XAML file I added the Application Namespace and this resolves the problem.

```
<Canvas x:Class="ZuneCardrintouch.Cards.Appointment.ZuneVertical" />
```